# Call a method from activty to service when app killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

i am working on a tracking app it woks in background as well as foreground. its working fine in foreground but when user kill it from stack it crashed.because i had some method call from activity to my service.can anyone tell me how i call a method from activity to service when app kill from stack? i am stuck on this from a long while but unable to found any solution.

here is the method which i called from activity to my service.

```
class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyActivity.instance.myfunction();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call methods in an `Activity` from a `Service` because the instance of the `Activity` may no longer be there.

The better way to do this is to have the `Service` send a broadcast `Intent`, which the `Activity` can listen for. If the `Activity` is gone, nothing will happen.